# Wildfly Clustering error changing session id

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, wildfly, infinispan

I am trying to setup clustering structure on Wildfly. I have tried Wildfly 8 and Wildfly 8.2 . My configurations are almost done but in one case I get lots of exceptions.

When a user tries first login I change its session with

```
request.changeSessionId(); //request is HttpServletRequest
```

On this line, I got lots of exception (approximately 3k lines). Some exceptions are;

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackEcxeption: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException: could not execute statement

[org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] (default task-16) ISPN000136: Execution error: org.infinispan.commons.CacheListenerException: ISPN000280: Caught exception [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException] while invoking method [public void org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager.removed(org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryRemovedEvent)] on listener instance: org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager@5fe90f10

Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ POST /500.html}: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to end batch.
```

These are some of the error. My stack trace is very much to share I believe so I put some of the exceptions.

As I said these errors happen when I try to change session. I don't know what can be the problem.

I hope someone face this error before and can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in WildFly 10.0.0.Final.  I strongly encourage you to upgrade, as 8.x is no longer an active branch.